# How to import Theta tokens to make dem viewable on the Metamask surface?

Tags: tokens, metamask

I have send Theta tokens via the Theta Mainnet to my Metamask Wallet. I can't "import" them though because I don't find the necessary contract address. Now the tokens are neither viewable on the Metamask surface (just in the Explorer) nor can I send them to another wallet again.

Can someone help me please? :)

Cheers,
Sarah Lisa

Answer (score 1):

If you've sent them via mainnet, you need to import the chain `(RPC, ChainId, ..)` to Metamask.
You can simply go to chainlist.org and add the Theta Mainnet from there by connecting your wallet (you can also add it manually by adding a new network in your metamask, with the Theta Mainnet data).

Direkt link to chainlist Theta Mainnet: https://chainlist.org/?search=theta

Add the network to your Metamask, and after adding the network, switch from Ethereum Mainnet (or whatever chain you are currently on) to the Theta Mainnet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not sure, I understand well. I already have set up the TFUEL Network in my Metamask. The point is that the tokens are not shown ON the Metamask surface but only in the Network Explorer. To import them on the surface I need the **contract address** and I don't know where to find it. As usually it's shown with the concerning transactionin in the Network explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like THETA tokens are not viewable on MetaMask. Only TFUEL is visible.
You can use the Theta web wallet to manage your tokens by importing the Metamask private key into Theta web wallet :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not viewable" - as is mentioned in other answers, it is possible to import tokens/chains into MM, could you elaborate?